# Erlang - Write a pattern that will bind a variable to the second element in this tuple {<0.206.0>, {rect, 10, 30}}

Tags: erlang, tuples

How do I write a pattern that will bind a variable to the second
element in this tuple {<0.206.0>, {rect, 10, 30}}?

I.e. "thing in place of pattern here" that results in 
Shape having the value {rect, 10, 30}.
*Pattern = {<0.206.0>, {rect, 10, 30}}*

It's the <0.206.0> part that is confusing me.

Answer (score 8):

As simple as this...

```
{_, Shape} = {<0.206.0>, {rect, 10, 30}}.
```

However, you cannot create a process-id from a literal, so the above syntax is wrong, but try this in the REPL...

```
1> {_, Shape} = {self(), {rect, 10, 30}}.
{<0.31.0>,{rect,10,30}}
2> Shape.
{rect,10,30}
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I was just about to post that self() worked, even if it gives different numbers. :)

The question is pretty weird though, since the lecturer hasn't talked about PIDs at all. Oh well, this should do.

Answer (score 4):

`<0.206.0>` looks like a PID.  It's just one thing either way, so don't think about it.

You can do what dsmith suggests, depending on your context, or you can just do this:

```
Shape = element(2, {<0.206.0>, {rect, 10, 30}}).
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for your further reference, you can use the `pid/0` function to "create" a specific Pid:

```
1> Pid = pid(0,206,0).
<0.206.0>
2> {Pid, Shape} = {Pid, {rect, 10, 30}}.
{<0.206.0>,{rect,10,30}}
```